# how to get a table from website using Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I followed some examples such as get data, from web, and inserting url. However, I can't seem to get the table.

here is the URL `https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/HVQ21/futures-prices`

How would I get that table chart into power query?

Comment: Members can download the data directly to excel.  Are you trying to circumvent the membership?  (We don't do that here)

Comment: I have membership. I don't want to download the data. I want to get the data into powerQuery from web not from a static download

Comment: I'd check to see if they have an ODATA or RESTful URL you can access the data from when logged in.

Comment: also, that data is the free version.

Comment: Have you look at similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558714/pull-value-from-website-html-div-class-using-excel-vba or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277464/how-to-import-a-table-from-web-page-with-div-class-to-excel?

Comment: I know how to do it using vba or python and import that into powerQ and refresh the file. I am specifically trying to do it just using powerQ. I looked at various sites and pages. it seems it should be as simple as clicking get data, from web, insert url, select table, transform, etc

Comment: Simple answer. You can't because thats not the URL. Its returned through javascript or other method to the screen, so powerquery cant grab it.  Things are rarely as simple as  clicking get data, from web, insert url, select table, transform

Comment: I see is there a workaround to get powerQ to grab that?

Comment: You probably could if you could determine the URL of the frame data being displayed, but I suspect it is either dynamic and/or just a container for a script, so likely not.